# Map Json Data to new key-value pair Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to map one json data to a new javascript object

**Before:**

```
{
    "Germany": 1,
    "France": 1
}
```

**After**

```
[
    {
        "name": "Germany",
        "anzahl": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "France",
        "anzahl": 1
    }
]
```

**Here's the code:**

```
const dataMap = Object.keys(s).map((filename, x) => {
      Object.keys(s[filename]).map((n) => ({
        anzahl: n
      }))
      return ({
        name: filename,
        anzahl: x
      });
    })
```

**Which is giving following output:**

```
[
    {
        "name": "Germany",
        "anzahl": 0
    },
    {
        "name": "France",
        "anzahl": 1
    }
]
```

Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.prototype.map`'s callback's second parameter is the current index of the array, which is why `x` is a number beginning at 0 and incrementing. If, instead, you write it as follows:

```js
const dataMap = Object.keys(s).map((filename) => {
    return {
        name: filename,
        anzahl: s[filename]
    }
});
```

This transforms each key of `s` into an object where `name` is said key, and `anzahl` is the result of accessing the key `filename` on object `s`.